# Having trouble aligning an instanced mesh to another object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes, instances

I am trying to create this [Geode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geode) and so far so good. However I can't seem to align these crystals I created so that they face inwardly. I have tried to align them using the Align Euler node to no avail and I have tried aligning their z axis to a little cube I created in the middle of the Geode so that its location could serve as a reference point.

I can't figure it out. I looked up other tutorials and I can't seem to find one that truly suffices my needs. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points you distribute on the faces are already aligned with it - so to make the crystals point outwards from the face normals (which in your case would make them point into the center), you just have to plug the *Rotation* output of the *Distribute Points on Faces* node into the *Rotation* input of the *Instance on Points* node (sorry for my poor modeling):

[image: point alignment]

If you now want to slightly randomize the rotation of the crystals so that they don't simply stick out straight in normal direction, you can give the rotations some *Random Value*.

To do that, plug the *Rotation* output from the distributed points into the *Rotation* input on a *Rotate Euler* node set to *Euler* and *Local*. Than plug a *Random Value* node set to *Vector* into the *Rotate By* input. X an Y values make the crystals deviate from the normal and Z rotates around the normal. The result of the *Rotate Euler* now goes into the *Rotation* input of the *Instance on Points* node.

[image: randomize rotation]

Comment: I was able to follow your instructions really well and it worked! It looks more or less how I imagined it. Thank you for the well constructed response, very thoughtful!